# Extjs 5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of null

Tags: extjs5

I changed extjs 4.2.3 to 5.0.1 and i have this error.Any ideas?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of null

Ext.define.extractDataext-all-debug.js:8144 Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParentext-all-debug.js:61852 Ext.define.extractDataext-all-debug.js:68174 Ext.define.onNodeInsertext-all-debug.js:68093 Ext.define.onNodeAppendext-all-debug.js:68329 Ext.define.updateRoot

Comment: In `extractData` method there is the line `schema = entityType.schema` which resolves schema from model type. That indicates that model must be null. Model is resolved above by this code: `readOptions && readOptions.model ? Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(readOptions.model) : me.getModel()`. One of this is null.

If you provided model in store or tree node via string check for typo.