# From Extjs4 to Extjs5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metaData' of null

Tags: ext4

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metaData' of null
I'm still having this error.I moved from Extjs 4 to 5.Any Ideas?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metaData' of nullext-all-debug.js:61885 Ext.define.createAccessor.resultext-all-debug.js:61791 
Ext.define.readRecordsext-all-debug.js:59803 
Ext.define.readext-all-debug.js:61444 
Ext.define.processResponseext-all-debug.js:61746 (anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:5750 Ext.apply.callbackext-all-debug.js:16297 
Ext.define.onCompleteext-all-debug.js:16236 
Ext.define.onStateChangeext-all-debug.js:4710 
Ext.Function.ExtFunction.bind
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extjs 5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169371/extjs-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-schema-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

The data object that is pass into the method is null. Make sure that in your proxy definition your're pointing to the correct data root in your payload. Moreover creating a Sencha Fiddle or JSFiddle will be pretty helpful to solve this issue.

Comment: thnx for the answeri ve got some sample code here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357686/extjs5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-metadata-of-null

Comment: Does it mean its a duplicate post or is this a different issue?